# Javascript function change variable value

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, function

I am currently developing signup page and I want to check if email address is already exist in the database.

```
var emailnum = email_num(`select * from contactinfo where email='${email}'`);
        console.log(emailnum); //the output presents Promise { <pending> } not a num.

function sqlExecute(q) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.pool.query(q, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("ERROR ON " + q+"\n");
                    reject(err)
                }
                console.log("SUCCESS ON " + q);
                resolve(result);
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}

//run check sql
async function email_num(tempquery){
   var result = await sqlExecute(tempquery);
   return result.rowCount;
}
```

### I tried multiple ways but still could not figure it out.
I would appreciate any help TT

when I console.log, output is Always Promise {  }.
I tried

```
var emailnum = email_num(`select count(*) as count from contactinfo where email='${email}'`)
.then((val)=>{
return val
};
console.log("number"+ emailnum);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're not allowing the promise to resolve before attempting to retrieve the row count. When you create a function using `async` the return result is always going to be a promise. Here are a few solutions that will get you your desired result:

Solution 1: Use `console.log` to print the result of the promise after it has been resolved.

```
const email = 'something@gmail.com'
const numOfEmailsQuery = `SELECT * FROM contactinfo WHERE email = '${email}'`

email_num(numOfEmailsQuery)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

Solution 2: Use `await` inside of an `async` function to resolve the result of the promise and store it in a variable. Then print the result using `console.log`

```
async function printNumberOfEmails(email) {
  const numOfEmailsQuery = `SELECT * FROM contactinfo WHERE email = '${email}'`
  try {
    const numOfEmails = await email_num(numOfEmailsQuery)
    console.log(numOfEmails)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}

const email = 'something@gmail.com'
printNumberOfEmails(email)
```

Hope that helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I tried both solution but still gives me Promise { <pending> }. I want to retry solution 2, and it doesn't need to return numOfEmails?

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's good practice to use prepared statements instead.

Also, you should just care about the count, so instead of `select *`, do `select count(*) as count`. Then you'll need check either the number of rows that `result` returned or the first index of rows, then the `count` property of that.

It should look something like this

```
function fetchEmailExists(email) {
    const statement = 'select count(*) as count from contactinfo where email = $1';
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.pool.query(statement, [ email ], function(error, result) {
                if (!error && result.rows.length > 0) {
                    resolve(result.rows[0]['count'] > 0);
                } else {
                    reject(error);
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

// Here is your call to fetchEmailExists
fetchEmailExists('test123@example.com')
  .then(boolean => console.log(boolean));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I tried the function with new query, when I console.log it still gives me Promise { <pending> }.

Comment: Where ever you're calling fetchEmailExists you have to call then on the promise.